# Looking for a simpler way to both center a table and have a margin on the right

Tags: css, html, html-table, scrollbar, margin

Is there a more elegant (simpler) way to create a html5/css table with the following two properties: 1) centered when smaller than the page; 2) having a working right margin when horizontal scrollbar appears on the page; other than what i did based on some suggestions found here and on other sites, and that's wrapping it in inner inline-block div and outer table div, shortly:

```
<DIV STYLE="display:table; margin:0 auto;">
<DIV STYLE="display:inline-block;">
<TABLE STYLE="margin-left:Npx; margin-right:Mpx...
```

Comment: Can you try to make an illustration of what you want? :)

Comment: Illustration of right margin of a table not working when it's larger than the page is given here, along with the remedy (my inner div wrapper). [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nnJ6F/5/) However, when i do that, i'm unable to center the table when it's thinner so i figured i add the outter wrapper. All this works, but i'm thinking there should be an easier way.

Comment: I meant a illustration/drawing of the result you wish to accomplish

Comment: just both right-margined (when large) and centered (when small) table.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but try this...

Put you `table` inside a wrapper, and use Flexbox with `justify-content: center` and `overflow: scroll`,

Then the table will be centered if it's smaller than the wrapper, and if it's bigger than the wrapper a horizontal scrollbar appears.

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2tqmm8g/)

Comment: perhaps my comment above will clarify the situation somewhat. when horizontal margin is added to your fiddle table, it doesn't show, and when it's added to the wrapper, it shows only on the left side (with the scrollbar present).